# Using pipe in a shell command

Tags: shell, pipe

Say I am in dired and the pointer is on a file called `test` which contains:

```
1. 
2. 
3. 
4. 
5. 
6. 
7. 
8. 
9. 
10. 
11. 
12. 
13. 
14. 
15. 
16. 
17. 
18. 
19. 
20.
```

I type `!` to run a shell command on this file.
I type `tac | head -n 2`

I get :

```
1.
2.
```

But I expected:

```
20.
19.
```

As if I has run `tac test | head -n 2` in the shell.

What am I misunderstanding and what is the correct way to get the behaviour I wish?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, `dired-do-shell-command` inserts the file name at the end of the command you enter. In effect, you are doing this:

```
tac | head -n 2 test
```

Without an argument, `tac` doesn't produce any output for your pipe, so `head` returns the first two lines of `test` and then you're done.

You can use the `?` symbol to tell dired to put your filename at that location in the command. i.e.,

```
tac ? | head -n 2
```

Comment: The docstring of `dired-do-shell-command` explains how to interpolate the relevant file name into the resulting command.